# Google play developer doesn't accept apk with vector drawable as the app icon

Tags: android, google-play, icons, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to upload my first app on the google play and I face error of

> Upload failed: You need to check the icon inside your APK because it
>   is not valid.

What I did is simple. Created and vector drawable icon and used it as the launcher icon for my app but it seems apk with vector drawables as the app icon is not acceptable with google play. I searched around about the ways I could convert my vector drawable to png but no success so far. The only solution remains is to convert vector to svg by hand and convert the svg to png and again import it to the android studio. Must say google play accept png format as the launcher icon and some apps like zapya can not show vector drawable icons which is assigned as the launcher.

Any suggestion to solve this problem or at least converting vector drawable to the png in a simple way?

Comment: Get Inkscape. They have an export function to convert from svg to png.

Comment: Thank you. Inkscape is helpful for converting and editing svg but working on raw svg code with Inkscape is not possible as far a I found out but there is an editor in Inkscape which is not as clean and simple as code editors like this >> http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.htm.

Comment: There is a code editor in inkscape. But, why would you want to code it? Drawing it is less time consuming.

Comment: I had a vector drawable created by android studio which is not readable by editors out there or online convertors. What I ended up to do was converting vector drawable standard codes to the svg standard codes line by line by hand to it become readable by Inkscape. Now I am editing my icon easily with your suggested software thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

1. Render the Vector in an ImageView
2. Get the Bitmap from the ImageView
3. Save the Bitmap to a PNG file

For some code see (it's exactly the same question, I just answered it ;O) ):
[Convert Android vector drawable to launcher icon PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373074/convert-android-vector-drawable-to-launcher-icon-png/41411839#41411839)